# How to make UIView go fullscreen when entering edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, model-view-controller, fullscreen

I have a UITableView that renders in the context of a UINavigationController (and maybe even a TabBarController). There is a way to make the UITableView enter editing mode. When that happens I want the table to get 'focused' and the navigation bar and tab bar to go away (the table view has to expand to fill the empty space). Then when editing mode completes, it should all go back to normal. Anyway to achieve this with standard iOS view and controller functionality. Or do I have to start hiding controls and resizing the view manually?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a modal view to accomplish this.

Have a look at the documentation for `[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]`

Comment: thanks, but does this work even if the uiview i want to go modal with is already on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the `UINavigationBar` and the `UITabBar` to disappear, you can just use:

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`

Otherwise, you can show an *editable* version of the `UITableViewController` and push it onto the navigation stack:

```
viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;  // this property needs to be set before pushing viewController to the navigationController's stack. 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks. Same question as below. Does this work for a view that is already active (so my table starts in the context of a tab bar controller, then the user taps on edit and the view needs to go modal